# Изменить radio на checkbox в тесте

Tags: javascript, html, input

Уважаемые форумчане, есть код теста(код ниже) который принимает значения блока состоящего из `<input type="radio">`с одинаковым id. Проверяет какое значение правильное и если выбран пункт с `value=1` то считает вопрос правильно отвеченным. Но мне понадобилось сделать несколько вариантов ответов. Но чтобы если хоть один из них неправильный, то весь вопрос считался неправильным. То есть если надо выбрать 3 варианта, то правильным засчитывался только ответ, с этими 3 отвеченными вариантами. Можете помочь реализовать именно JS проверку?

```js
function count() {
  answer = 0;
  answerBlocksCount = document.form1.getElementsByTagName("p").length;
  questionsCount = document.form1.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').length + 1;
  var ball = 0;
  var good = "";
  var bad = "";
  var solv = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < questionsCount; i++) {
    if (document.form1.elements[i].checked) {
      if (document.form1.elements[i].value != 0) {
        if (good != "") {
          good += ", " + solv;
        } else {
          good += "№ " + solv;
        }
      } else {
        if (bad != "") {
          bad += ", " + solv;
        } else {
          bad += "№ " + solv;
        }
      }
      solv++;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < questionsCount; i++) {
    if (document.form1.elements[i].checked) {
      answer += 1;
    }
  }
  if (answer < answerBlocksCount) {
    alert("Вы не ответили на все вопросы теста!");
  } else {
    if (good == "") good = " нет :(";
    if (bad == "") bad = " нет =)";

    var answer = "<span style=color:green>Решены правильно:</span> " + good + "<br>";
    if (bad == "нет") {
      answer += "Неправильно: " + bad + ".";
    } else {
      answer += "<span style=color:red>Неправильно:</span>" + bad + "";
    }

    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("gecko") > 0) {
      div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    }
    div1.innerHTML = answer;
    div1.style.display = 'block';

    var paragraphs = document.form1.getElementsByTagName("i").length;
    for (s = 0; s < paragraphs.length; s++) {
      if (document.form1.elements[s].checked) {
        paragraphs(s).style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        if (document.form1.elements[s].value != 0) {
          paragraphs(s).style.color = 'green';
        } else {
          paragraphs(s).style.color = 'red';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" class="test">
  <p>1. Вопрос 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="1"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>
  </p>
  <p>2. Вопрос 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="1"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

  </p>
  <p>3. Вопрос 3
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="1"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

  </p>
  <div border="1" id="div1" style="padding:9px 0 11px 10px;margin:9px 17px;border:1px solid green;display:none;"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Узнать результат" onclick="count();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во первых вам стоит заменить все `radio` на `checkbox` т.к. так будет проще выставлять более одного варианта ответа. О том, как проверять ответы да и вообще представление ответов - это уже на ваше усмотрение:

**1.** Можно сделать просто массив, где каждый элемент - это еще один массив  который описывает ответ на один вопрос( например `var otv[] = [1,3,5]; var massOtv=[otv,otv,...]`)  и потом при проверке одного блока чекбоксов сравивать выбранные элементы с массивом.

Типа
 `if (massOtv[j][k] == checkbox[i].val())` где i и j и л  это разные счетчики т.к. вариантов ответа и самих ответов может быть разное кол-во (т.е. j cчитаем до massOtv.length - т.е. это ваш номер вопроса, k - перебор вариантов ответа). Проверка правильности - если кол-во совпавших ответов равно massOtv[j].length, то ответ верный.

**2.** Можно и иначе - можно сделать зараннее массив для ответа "полной длинны" т.е. если предполагается всего 5 вариантов ответа то и массив `massOtv[5]`. В в нем правильные варианты ответа можно пометить как 1 , неправильные - 0 и также прогонять при проверке.

**3.** Ответ в виде строки "2;3;5", которую проще хранить, но сложнее парсить (т.е. перед проверкой нужно или 1) "сложить" варианты ответа с чепкбоксов в строку или же 2) распарсить строку ответа для удобного сравнения. )

Проверка зависит от выбранного "стиля" вашего массива ответов. Если я описал немного "сложно", то напишите что именно не ясно и я постараюсь дополнить ответ.